# 1071 specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a migration like this:

```
Schema::create('migration1', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->increments('id');
 $table->string('endpoint',500)->unique();
})
```

when i run migration i'm getting:

```
1071 specified key was too long; max key length is 1000
```

in my boot method i have :

```
  public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

Comment: Add this on migration `$table->engine = "InnoDB";` if it will not work, then you may try with,  to change the charset `utf8mb4` to `utf8`

Comment: Is boot method in Service provider?

Comment: Is there `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`  in your `AppServiceProvider.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Schema::create('migration1', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->engine = "InnoDB";
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('endpoint',500)->unique();
})
```